# Is the PNPDeviceID unique

Tags: wmi-query

I wonder if the PNPDeviceID of an USB drive is unique (at least for a charge of identical devices) and if the ID does not change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know -- No. For example, "USBSTOR\DISK&VEN_LG&PROD_USB_DRIVE&REV_1100\AA04012700014149**&0**" - is a device id of a usb stick. For all such given usb sticks device id will be the same. But Windows adds an instance id of device ("**&0**"), so it can distinguish them. If you plug two same usb sticks the device id of each of them will be different, for example: USBSTOR\DISK&VEN_LG&PROD_USB_DRIVE&REV_1100\AA04012700014149**&0** USBSTOR\DISK&VEN_LG&PROD_USB_DRIVE&REV_1100\AA04012700014149**&1**

P.S. Sometimes Windows doesn't add instance of a device, if another same device isn't plugged. (I don't know why)

Comment: But if I remove the last part after the "&"? Does it still change?

Comment: @addy20120 no, it will not change.